# What does the phrase "Mind your business" mean or refer to?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, idiom-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase "Mind your business", as used on the 'Fugio Cent' copper penny, during the period of the Congress of the Confederation in America?

Comment: fugio cent is a coin?

Comment: ok.  aka the 'sunshine', the f'ranklin', the 'ring' and the 'mind your business' cents

Comment: [RiverGrandRapids](http://rivergrandrapids.com/the-first-official-us-coin-said-mind-your-business-fact-of-the-day/) answers this in the second article that turned up in a Google search. I assume the Wikipedia article also gives the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I appreciate it if you respond to or comment on the meaning of "Mind your business", as used on the Fugio Cent in Colonial America?"

My comment as per wikipedia:

> Fugio cent: because of its image of the sun shining down on a sundial
>   with the caption, "Fugio" (Latin: I flee/fly). This coin was
>   reportedly designed by Benjamin Franklin; as a reminder to its
>   holders, he put at its bottom the message, "Mind Your Business." The
>   image and the words form a rebus meaning that "time flies, do your
>   work." [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugio_Cent)

As in:

> Your time is passing ... get to your tasks that need to be done.

[image: fugio dollar] this image is from the dollar issued.  It is said it was also on the coin.

[image: the coin] found it.